# Excel – Generating Word document using VB Script

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I have a bunch of VB script in Excel that ultimately opens up a new Word document and places a bunch of information in it. Everything works well, but I am having one annoyance. The annoyance is that sometimes the Word document will open in front of everything else and sometimes it will open behind everything else.

I have tried duplicating the results and it appears to be random. Sometimes I think there is something consistent as to why it does it and then something happens so my theory doesn’t hold true. I must have generated the Word document over 100 times trying different stuff and can’t seem to figure it out.

I do have three monitors, running Office 2010, and Windows 7. I am not sure if the three monitors would have any affect as to why it isn’t consistent.

What I want is for it to be visible in front of everything when it opens.

This is the code I am using to make it visible and I tried it at the end, the beginning, and then at both the end and beginning of where it creates the document:

```
        wrdApp.Activate
        wrdApp.Visible = True
```

Anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: _I have a bunch of VB script in Excel_ Do you mean `VBA`? (vbscript and VBA are _not_ the same thing)

Comment: Well, it is script within Microsoft Excel, so I don't think that is the same as VBA. Like if you go to Excel, right click on a sheet and select View Code. Please correct me if I am wrong in calling it script, but I thought VBA was different.

Comment: That _is_ VBA.  Please update your tags.  Also to get help you will need to post more of your code, eg how `wrdApp` is created

Comment: If can't open word in a controlled way / synchronously (ie. wait for app to open, it reports when it's done/ready), try to "wait" (sleep) for app load to happen, then DoEvents, then the visibility code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want is for it to be visible in front of everything when it opens.

No need for APIs for this.

Instead of this

```
    wrdApp.Activate
    wrdApp.Visible = True
```

Use this

```
    wrdApp.Visible = True
    wrdApp.Activate
```

You can't really activate it if it is not visible. Also ensure that the **last line** in your macro before you destroy the object is `wrdApp.Activate`. You wouldn't want the `wrdApp` to loose focus because of any other code...

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe this works. I can't get it to open behind other applications, even after many attempts. Thanks!

Comment: You can. Simply activate the current excel application. :)